# Intuition for convex hull

Tags: geometry

For some set $V \subset [a,b]^d$, define the convex hull of $V$ as the set

$$\{\lambda_1v_1 + ... + \lambda_kv_k: \ \lambda_i \ge 0, \ v_i \in V, \ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i = 1, k = 1, 2, 3, ...\}.$$

I don't understand why exactly these vectors form the convex hull of $V$. Why wouldn't I be able to choose $\lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_j = 0$ for $j \neq i$ and thus make every $v_i \in V$ be a part of the convex hull?

Comment: But every $v_i$ is in the convex hull!

Comment: But that would mean $conv(V) = V$.

Comment: For instance, if you choose $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\frac12,$ you get the point midway betweev $v_1$ and $v_2$; that's probably not in $V$ but it is in the convex hull.

Comment: But if it's in the convex hull but not in $V$, then $conv(V) \subset V$ wouldn't be correct in this case.

Comment: You probably meant $V \subset conv(V)$?

Comment: Please correct a bit your sum,  it should start from 1 not 0...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $V\subset conv(V).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following picture, the convex hull of the set of black points is the region inside of the red line.

[image]

So yes, the convex hull of the $v_i$ contains each $v_i$.

Comment: So it is the region inside of the red line but the red line itself is not a part of the convex hull?

Comment: The red line is part of the convex hull with only two lambdas not null

Comment: @Julian The red line is also part of the convex hull.

Answer (score 1):

Any convex set $C$ which contains $v_1,\dots,v_k$, also contains  the segments $[v_i,v_j]\;(1\le i,j\le k)$. These  segments have a parametric representation $\;tv_i+(1-t)v_j\;(0\le t\le1)$, which we may rewrite, setting $\lambda_i=t$, $\lambda_j=1-t$: 
$$\lambda_iv_i+\lambda_jv\in C,\quad\lambda_i,\lambda_j\ge 0,\enspace\lambda_i+\lambda_j=1.$$
In other words, $C$ must contain all barycenters of $v_i$ and $v_j$ with non-negative weights.

An easy induction shows it must contain all barycenters of $v_1,\dots, v_k$ with non-negative weights, which is essentially what the definition says.